# Image won't load in HTML

Tags: python, html, image

I'm not sure why but my image isn't loading. Here's how I grab it in my code:

```
<img src="IMG_4772.jpg" alt="Cereal Logo">
```

Here's how I have my files organized:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdxgW.png)

Not sure why it wouldn't be loading in?

Comment: You can't load local files if you're not using a web server to serve your html file.

Comment: any console error?

Comment: No I don't have any errors. What do you mean by can't load local files? I'm running a local server by doing python3 "table.py" in my terminal

Comment: Your html assumes that IMG_4882.jpg is in the same folder as your html file - is that the case?

Comment: Yes, they're both in templates (see the screenshot image)